# React (or angular) + JWT Authentication + Session/Cookies

Tags: angular, reactjs, authentication, jwt

My application server uses JWT authentication and my front end is React (but might as well be Angular for the purpose of this question).

First time a user logs in, The app exchange the user provided username+password and gets a JWT token to make internal API requests to the application server.

From a UX experience, I would really like users not to have to type their username+password every time they go to "myapp.com". But that presents another issue. JWT keys are usually short lived for security purposes and must be renewed with either the old JWT (for a short while), or with a new username+password after the "lifespan" of the key ends and no more renewals are permitted.

What's the common practice in this case to maintain a hassle free UX? have the JWT keys unnaturally long lived and just retain the JWT token using cookies or actually retain the username + password in cookies? I would be very surprised if this were the case.

Does it make sense to encode the JWT with the IP address of the user, and give it indefinite life? So if someone else (or the user himself) uses a different location, he/she would have to re-enter their password and get an indefinite key for that location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern we follow is, we usually have the token expiry set to a day for the user identity token. And something like 3-4 hours for access token.

When user logs in, we get the identity token using his credentials and store it in localStorage. Then we fire another request to fetch the client access token for the webapp using the identity token we have, and save the client access token in sessionStorage.

For all subsequent requests, we pick it up from session storage and send it along with the request.

When user closes the tab (session) the access token is lost, and it is re-obtained next time when he opens again using the identity token.

So he has to login once in a day.

If you are more concerned about someone stealing the tokens from the storages, you can encrypt and decrypt the tokens using AES.

Hope this helps.